# Getting NullRefrenceException Unhandled By User Code

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting the following error at line `_dict.Add(id, ar)`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

This is my code:

```
public Dictionary<int, byte[]> _dict;

public IDictionary<int, byte[]> dict()
{
    string sp = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Images");
    DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(sp);
    FileInfo[] files = folder.GetFiles("*.jpg");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        string name = file.Name;
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(name.Substring(0, name.Length - 4));
        FileStream fS = new FileStream(sp + "\\" + name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] ar = new byte[fS.Length];
        fS.Read(ar, 0, (int)fS.Length);
        fS.Close();
        _dict.Add(id, ar);
    }
    return _dict;
}
```

Comment: You never initialize _dict

Comment: thnks all for ur suggestions and editing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

_dict has never been instantiated. change it so its like:

```
public Dictionary<int, byte[]> _dict = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
```

Comment: thnks Kevin __i forgot initialize dict :)